# Finding the ID for football-data API

Tags: python, database, api

Every team is represented by an ID.

E.G. In the example provided, **`66`** represents *`Manchester United`*

http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/66

I'm unable to find what team each ID represents without 'trial and error' and going through the numbers since I can't find any DOC or source.

Is there a way, or a source, to find what each ID represents without simply going through manually?

http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/`{id}`

---

[Documentation](http://api.football-data.org/documentation)  - `http://api.football-data.org/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://api.football-data.org/docs/v1/index.html#_team) you can search for teams as well, example for Mancher United would be like follows:

```
http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams?name=Manchester%20United
```

If you know the competition the team is part of you could also get the list of all teams and grab the specific team id from there. An example for the Premier League would be like follows:

```
http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/398/teams
```

Comment: Please follow the provided link! Idea regarding the ID? I don't get you. You don't want to do determine the ID of a specific team by trial and error. So, use the search or go via the competition to get a smaller list of teams (see answer).

Comment: I did. The answer is, use the search provided by the API. It is that simple.

Comment: Using the collection resource which is the entry point to the API: http://api.football-data.org/docs/v1/index.html#_competition. Providing the parameter season.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130421/discussion-between-matbtt-and-benf97).